# Sorting 1D array by two items

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm seeking to sort this football league table by Pts and then GD.

```
var league2=[
  "Team,P,W,D,L,GD,Pts",
  "teamA,6,2,0,2,4,6",
  "teamB,6,1,1,6,2,7",
  "teamC,6,2,1,8,8,7"
  ];
```

Using this code:

```
console.log(league2.sort((a, b) => b[5] - a[5] || b[4] - a[4]));
```

This was based on the good advice I received here based on a slightly different version of this array:

```
var league1=[
  ["teamA",6,2,0,2,7],
  ["teamB",6,1,1,6,7],
  ["teamC",6,2,1,8,7]];

console.log(league1.sort((a, b) => b[5] - a[5] || b[4] - a[4]));
```

This results in an unsorted league2 unfortunately.

I am beginning to wonder that  eague2 is not an array anymore but a list of strings?  If so, is there another way of sorting league2?

PS The reason I changed league2 was so to display it within a HTML table but I may need to go back to the drawing board...

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn each element into an array again:

```js
var league2=[
  "Team,P,W,D,L,GD,Pts",
  "teamA,6,2,0,2,4,6",
  "teamB,6,1,1,6,2,7",
  "teamC,6,2,1,8,8,7"
  ]; 

console.log(league2.map(x => x.split(',')).sort((a, b) => b[5] - a[5] || b[4] - a[4]));
```

Comment: Thank you *Dupocas* and others for your help.  It's appreciated.   Given I intend to re-calculate the league based on new scores, is it wise to revert back to the league1 'proper' array?

Answer (score 1):

You could first check if the values are finite and take non finite values at top. Then sort by the wanted columns.

```js
var league2 = ["Team,P,W,D,L,GD,Pts", "teamA,6,2,0,2,4,6", "teamB,6,1,1,6,2,7", "teamC,6,2,1,8,8,7"];

league2.sort((a, b) => {
    var aa = a.split(','),
        bb = b.split(',');
    return isFinite(aa[5]) - isFinite(bb[5]) || bb[5] - aa[5] || bb[4] - aa[4];
}); 

console.log(league2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new empty array of the same size, and place an integer representation of the index of the end of the string to the last comma inside of it. You could then sort that list looking for the highest integer, and the index of where that integer is in that array is the same as the index of the team with the highest points. Sort league 2 by comparing ints

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your columns are not separated out in league2. Everything is in 1 string. You could solve this using split, though it is not terrible efficient

```
var league2=[
  "Team,P,W,D,L,GD,Pts",
  "teamA,6,2,0,2,4,6",
  "teamB,6,1,1,6,2,7",
  "teamC,6,2,1,8,8,7"
  ]; 

console.log(league2.sort(function(a,b) {a = a.split(","); b = b.split(","); return b[5] - a[5] || b[4] - a[4] }) );
```